# php variables correctly pass inside the jquery or javascript highchart

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

click here for jsfiddle highchart link: [Column - Bar High Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/)

this code is the actual code of the Column bar highchart, is there a way to make its graph base on php varible.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 100,
                y: 70,
                floating: true,
                shadow: true
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
                series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [100, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

            }]
        });
    });

});
//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Question
is this possible "
`[100, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]`"

to became

```
[<?php $newval1.",".$newval2.",".$newval3.",".$newval4.",".$newval5.",".$newval6.",".$newval7.",".$newval8.",".$newval9.",".$newval10.",".$newval11.",".$newval12 ?>]
```

so that the value are from php variables, correct me.. thanks

Comment: yes you can do that.. are facing any problem?

Comment: yes, for example i place this <?php $newval1=100 ?> on the top of the script, the 100 bar graph is not showing

Comment: @RobertJohnConcepcion have you assigned the `$newval` into the javascript, or before the javascript??

Comment: before java script, <?php $newval1=100 ?> i add this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a string of this in PHP something like this:

```
<?php 
$newval1 = "100";
$newval2 = "250";
..... // Your variables

// Now pass the values to make the string
$str = "[$newval1, $newval2, $newval3, $newval4, $newval5, $newval6, $newval7]";
?>
```

and apply in javascript like :

```
data: <?php echo $str; ?>
```

Comment: sir how about this <?php $newval1 = 10; newval2 = 20;  
$str = "[$newval1, $newval2, $newval3, $newval4, $newval5, $newval6, $newval7]";
?> so that it will have a value

Comment: @RobertJohnConcepcion yes of cause it is like same, i give you just an example that how do you create a string and how to pass that string to javascript, its the same way, hope this working for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but you have to do:

```
[<?php echo $newval1.",".$newval2.",".$newval3.",".$newval4.",".$newval5.",".$newval6.",".$newval7.",".$newval8.",".$newval9.",".$newval10.",".$newval11.",".$newval12; ?>]
```

this is the exact same as you have now except you forgot the added `echo`.